# Is there a polyfill for findAll

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am using JavaScript findAll for a selector engine. Is there any polyfill for the `findAll` function. I tried to create my own selector engine with this code:

```
function CTfind(string, context){
    var result = [], finalResult = [];
    if(typeof string === "object"){
        result.push(string);
        return result;
    }
    if(/<([a-zA-Z]+)(\s*)?\/>/ig.test(string)){
        var str = string.replace(/<([a-zA-Z]+)(\s*)?\/>/ig, "$1");
        var ret = document.createElement(str);
        if(typeof context === "object"){
            for(i in context)
                ret[i] = context[i];
        }
        document.body.appendChild(ret);
        result.push(ret);
        return result;
    } else{
        if(typeof string !== "string" && typeof string !== "object") return false;
        var documentElements = context.getElementsByTagName("*"),
        toMatch = string.split(", ");
        for(i = 0; i < documentElements.length; i++){
            for(e = 0; e < toMatch.length; e++){
                var stringParts = toMatch[e].split(" ");
                for(s = 0; s < stringParts.length; s++){
                    var parts;
                    if(/(\.|\#|\:)/g.test(stringParts[s])){
                        parts = stringParts[s].match(/([A-Za-z]+|[\.\#\:]+[^\.\#\:]+)/g);
                    } else if(/^(?!(\.|\#|\:)$).*$/g.test(stringParts[s])){
                        parts = stringParts[s];
                        var onlyElem = true;
                    }
                    if(onlyElem === true){
                        console.log(documentElements[i].nodeName);
                        if(documentElements[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() === parts){
                            result.push(documentElements[i]);
                        }
                    } else{
                        var containsClass = false,
                            containsElem = false,
                            containsID = false,
                            containsPseudo = false,
                            matchID = false,
                            matchElem = false,
                            matchClass = false,
                            matchPseudo = false;
                        if(/\./.test(stringParts[s])){
                            containsClass = true;
                        }
                        if(/\#/.test(stringParts[s])){
                            containsID = true;
                        }
                        if(/\:/.test(stringParts[s])){
                            containsPseudo = true;
                        }
                        if(/[^\.\#\:](.*)/.test(stringParts[s])){
                            containsElem = true;
                        }
                        if(containsElem === true){
                            var elem;
                            for(g = 0; g < parts.length; g++){
                                if(/^([^\.\#\:][A-Za-z])*$/.test(parts[g])){
                                    elem = parts[g];
                                } else{
                                    elem = documentElements[i].nodeName.toLowerCase();
                                }
                            }
                            if(documentElements[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() === elem){
                                matchElem = true;
                            }
                        } else{
                            matchElem = true;
                        }
                        if(containsID === true){
                            var id = filter(parts, "#");
                            id = id[0].substr(1);
                            if(getAttr(documentElements[i], "id") === id){
                                matchID = true;
                            }
                        } else{
                            matchID = true;
                        }
                        if(containsClass === true){
                            var classes = filter(parts, ".");
                            if(typeof classes === "string"){
                                classes = classes[0].split(".");
                                for(c = 0; c < classes.length; c++){
                                    if(classes[c] !== ""){
                                        if(hasClass(documentElements[i], classes[c])){
                                            matchClass = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else{
                            matchClass = true;
                        }
                        if(matchClass && matchID && matchElem){
                            result.push(documentElements[i]);
                        }
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                }
                if(stringParts.length > 1){
                    console.log(result);
                    if(isDescendant(result[0], result[result.length - 1])){
                        finalResult.push(result[result.length - 1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return finalResult;
    }
};
```

But I thought using Javascript `findAll` would be much easier. Also, I can't use `querySelector` because sometimes I need to find it in a specific node.

Comment: I haven't heard of `findAll` before so I looked it up on [**w3**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/#interface-definitions), `document.findAll; // undefined, chrome 35` Is this implemented by any browsers yet? Further, I don't understand what you mean in your reasoning for not wanting to use `querySelector`; what is wrong with `element.querySelector` rather than `document.querySelector`?

Comment: @PaulS. I could only find a polyfill for querySelector for document.querySelector and not for element.querySelector

Comment: It should be pretty easy to modify a polyfil for the document version into the element version; most of the methods still exist

Comment: jQuery can do this stuff easily, and comes with polyfills.

Comment: @Scimonster I want to create my own selector engine.